# Does breaking a Swift do-while loop with a UIButton press require a new thread?

Tags: multithreading, swift, uibutton, do-while

In the program below, I have two for-loops counting from 0 to 20 and then back down to 0.  Those loops are inside a do-while loop that is checking for value of a boolean.  The boolean is changed by a button press.

I have searched and searched on SO for the answer.  There is someone who asked the same question, but nobody answered.  His question appears here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/27223106/3140521

I think the answer is to use a new thread, but is there an easier way to do it?

Thank you,

Eli

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var keepGoing:Bool = true
    var i:Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func stopLoop(sender: UIButton) {
        mainLabel.text = "Off"
        keepGoing = false
    }

    @IBAction func startLoop(sender: UIButton) {
        keepGoing = true
        mainLabel.text = "On"

        do {
            for i = 1; i < 20; ++i {
                println(i)
            }

            for i = 20; i > -1; --i {
                println(i)
            }

        } while keepGoing == true

        println("Loop Broken")
    }
}
```

Comment: In real life how long will you be waiting for the boolean value?  Is it an arbitrarily long period or a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 4):

Button actions are performed on the main thread, as are all UI interactions.  Since you are executing a "long running" (it's not, but that's the intent) action on the main thread, no further UI interaction is possible until `startLoop` terminates, so no button presses will be recognized.

Your counting loop must be executed on a different thread to do what you seem to be wanting to do.

Note that "on a different thread" still means that you have a wide variety of options available to you with different advantages and disadvantages:

- NSThread - obviously, this creates an additional thread
- pthread - obviously, this creates an additional thread, but should be avoided in polite society
- NSOperationQueue - hides the thread creation behind an abstraction and allows a thread to be reused
- dispatch_queue - again, this hides thread creation and management behind an abstraction and for most purposes is the preferred mechanism to use these days.